# Show full stored function or procedure code in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, function-definition

How do you view a stored function or procedure?

Say I have an old function without the original definition - I want to see what it is doing in pg/psql but I can't seem to figure out a way to do that.

using Postgres version 8.4.1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

use pgAdmin or use [pg_proc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-proc.html) to get the source of your stored procedures. pgAdmin does the same.

Comment: pg_proc that's it! Whew I'm glad they saved a few bytes of space by not calling it pg_procedure...geez. :)

Comment: It's pretty easy to find out which queries psql is using to retrieve that information (e.g. for the \df command) by starting psql with the --echo-hidden parameter. That will show all queries that are used internally.
pg_proc does not store a complete CREATE FUNCTION statement. You can use  pg_get_functiondef() to retrieve the complete source.

Comment: just in case anyone is confused as to where that table is:
pg_catalog -> system table -> pg_proc

Answer (score 295):

`\df+ <function_name>` in [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html).

Comment: Is there a way to pretty print this? The reason I ask is because this makes it unreadable.

Comment: This is pretty printed, for me. Remember if you're doing this interactively in psql and lines get wrapped and the pager kicks in, then you can toggle wrapped lines off by typing '-S' (same as 'less' command line arg), then use arrow keys to scroll around.

Comment: For legibility, you can use the `\x` [psql meta-command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html) before displaying the function definition. `\x` is also useful for viewing query results containing records with long strings.

Answer (score 190):

`\ef <function_name>` in psql. It will give the whole function with editable text.

Comment: Exact answer. This will open function definition in editor.

Comment: This is the best answer! It shows function's definition in readable way.

Comment: Don't forget to type `;` `<enter>` after to execute the buffer.

Comment: `ERROR:  more than one function named`

Comment: @BrianCannard, no error if you add `(type)` of the needle function

Comment: Does this open it in vi editor? I guess esc+:+q+Etr gets me out of that editor

Comment: WOW! That's awesome! For so many years I didn't know about the \e directive to edit! This is mega cool!

Answer (score 91):

```
SELECT prosrc FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'function_name';
```

This tells the function handler how to invoke the function. It might be the actual source code of the function for interpreted languages, a link symbol, a file name, or just about anything else, depending on the implementation language/call convention

Comment: This is useful.  Is there a way to have the output pretty-printed?

Comment: This is useful because it doesn't require `psql`. Note that function names appear to be downcased.

Comment: @Maxim, do you know how to detect return type and input arguments ?

Comment: @Fivell, for just arg names, not types: `SELECT proname, prosrc, proargnames FROM pg_proc WHERE proname like '%func_name%'`. This at least on Pg 9.6. You can get the numeric code of the type through property `proargtypes`, but you'd need to join with some other table to get this as names.

Answer (score 18):

Use `\df` to list all the stored procedure in Postgres.

Answer (score 14):

If anyone wonders how to quickly query catalog tables and make use of the `pg_get_functiondef()` function here's the sample query:

```
SELECT n.nspname AS schema
      ,proname AS fname
      ,proargnames AS args
      ,t.typname AS return_type
      ,d.description
      ,pg_get_functiondef(p.oid) as definition
--      ,CASE WHEN NOT p.proisagg THEN pg_get_functiondef(p.oid)
--            ELSE 'pg_get_functiondef() can''t be used with aggregate functions'
--       END as definition
  FROM pg_proc p
  JOIN pg_type t
    ON p.prorettype = t.oid
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN pg_description d
    ON p.oid = d.objoid
  LEFT OUTER
  JOIN pg_namespace n
    ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
 WHERE NOT p.proisagg
   AND n.nspname~'<$SCHEMA_NAME_PATTERN>'
   AND proname~'<$FUNCTION_NAME_PATTERN>'
```

Comment: pg_get_functiondef()  seems not to handle  user defined aggregate functions. As I get ERROR:  "histogram" is an aggregate function when I query  a UDA

Comment: [42809] ERROR: "array_agg" is an aggregate function

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch corrected (to simply exclude aggregate functions)

Comment: You saved my life... pg_get_functiondef() can be used to find procs with specific word in the definition ```pg_get_functiondef(p.oid)  ilike '%indicator_loss%'```

Comment: As of v11, replace `NOT p.proisagg` with `NOT (p.prokind = 'a') `

Answer (score 12):

Since [PostgreSQL 9.1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/app-psql.html) `\sf` is available.

Comment: This answer is the most direct solution for the question. It deserves more votes.

Answer (score 8):

```
\sf function_name
```

(don't put a semicolon at the end)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT pg_get_functiondef(( SELECT oid 
                            FROM   pg_proc
                            WHERE  proname = 'function_name' ));
```

Answer (score 1):

*In this answer, I introduce several ways to show the code of a function as shown below but you can also use these ways below to show the code of a procedure.

For example, you create `my_func()` function as shown below.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(v1 INT, v2 INT) RETURNS INT
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN v1 + v2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, you can show the code of `my_func()` with [\sf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-SF) as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# \sf public.my_func
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_func(v1 integer, v2 integer)       
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  RETURN v1 + v2;
END;
$function$

postgres=# \sf+ public.my_func
        CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_func(v1 integer, v2 integer
)
         RETURNS integer
         LANGUAGE plpgsql
1       AS $function$
2       BEGIN
3         RETURN v1 + v2;
4       END;
5       $function$
```

*Memos:

- `+` can show line numbers.
- You can omit the schema `public.`.

Or, you can show the code of `my_func()` with [pg_get_functiondef()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html) and the OID(Object identifier) of `my_func()` as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT pg_get_functiondef('public.my_func'::regproc);
                        pg_get_functiondef
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.my_func(v1 integer, v2 integer)+
  RETURNS integer                                                 +
  LANGUAGE plpgsql                                                +
 AS $function$                                                    +
 BEGIN                                                            +
   RETURN v1 + v2;                                                +
 END;                                                             +
 $function$                                                       +

(1 row)
```

*Memos:

- You can omit the schema `public.`.

Or, you can show only the body code of `my_func()` with [pg_proc][4] as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT prosrc FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'my_func';
      prosrc
-------------------
                  +
 BEGIN            +
   RETURN v1 + v2;+
 END;             +

(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT prosrc FROM pg_proc WHERE oid = 'public.my_func'::regproc;
      prosrc
-------------------
                  +
 BEGIN            +
   RETURN v1 + v2;+
 END;             +

(1 row)
```

Or, you can show only the code of `my_func()` with [information_schema.routines](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/infoschema-routines.html) as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT routine_definition FROM information_schema.routines WHERE routine_name = 'my_func';
 routine_definition
--------------------
                   +
 BEGIN             +
   RETURN v1 + v2; +
 END;              +

(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get by phpPgAdmin if you are configured it in your system,

Step 1: Select your database

Step 2: Click on find button

Step 3: Change search option to functions then click on Find.

You will get the list of defined functions.You can search functions by name also, hope this answer will help others.

Answer (score 0):

```html
jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT routine_name FROM information_schema.routines WHERE routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'", String.class);
```

Answer (score -3):

Normally speaking you'd use a DB manager application like [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/), browse to the object you're interested in, and right click your way to "script as create" or similar.

Are you trying to do this... without a management app?

Comment: Just the command line - no management app.  If pgAdmin can do it, it has to be using some sort of command - I just can't find any documentation about it.  I'm looking through the pg_* tables but none seem to stand out.

Comment: Glad you found an answer, but not sure why you're making life hard for yourself! Why not just install pgAdmin?

Comment: When connecting to a db remotely in ssh session it is not easy to run a management app.