# Show the code of a function, procedure and trigger in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

How can I show the code of a function, procedure and trigger in PostgreSQL? Please let me know if any one know the query to show the code of them.

Comment: as a note for followers who got here trying to figure out how to list all triggers, it's `select * from pg_trigger;` or, if you also want to see which table each trigger applies to `select tgrelid::regclass, tgname from pg_trigger;` FWIW
`

Comment: The `\sf` (explanation [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38341540/287948)) is the best way to see function's source code.

Answer (score 224):

`\df+` in *psql* gives you the sourcecode.

Comment: Nice one :)  I suggest using `\df` to find the name of your function, then `\x` for expanded output, then `\df+ name_of_function`

Comment: \df+ outputs a lot more than the code. If all you want is the code, \sf will do the trick!

Comment: How to see **functions of an installed EXTENSION?**  Example I am using [ltree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ltree.html), but there are no response with `\df ltxtquery`.

Comment: `\x ON` is a must for transposed display

Comment: why  \sf+ Coalesce wrote me ERROR:  function "Coalesce" does not exist

Answer (score 168):

**For function:**

you can query the pg_proc view , just as the following

```
select proname,prosrc from pg_proc where proname= your_function_name;
```

Another way is that just execute the commont `\df` and `\ef` which can list the functions.

```
skytf=> \df           
                                             List of functions
 Schema |         Name         | Result data type |              Argument data types               |  Type  
--------+----------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------+--------
 public | pg_buffercache_pages | SETOF record     |                                                | normal


skytf=> \ef  pg_buffercache_pages
```

It will show the source code of the function.

**For triggers:**

I dont't know if there is a direct way to get the source code. Just know the following way, may be it will help you!

- step 1 : Get the table oid of the trigger:

```
    skytf=> select tgrelid from pg_trigger  where tgname='insert_tbl_tmp_trigger';
      tgrelid
    ---------
       26599
    (1 row)
```

- step 2: Get the table name of the above oid !

```
    skytf=> select oid,relname  from pg_class where oid=26599;
      oid  |           relname           
    -------+-----------------------------
     26599 | tbl_tmp
    (1 row)
```

- step 3: list the table information

```
    skytf=> \d tbl_tmp
```

It will show you  the details of the trigger of the table . Usually a trigger uses a function. So you can get the source code of the trigger function just as the above that I pointed out !

Answer (score 64):

Here are few examples from PostgreSQL-9.5

**Display list:**

1. Functions: `\df+`
2. Triggers : `\dy+`

**Display Definition:**

```
postgres=# \sf
function name is required

postgres=# \sf pg_reload_conf()
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.pg_reload_conf()
 RETURNS boolean
 LANGUAGE internal
 STRICT
AS $function$pg_reload_conf$function$

postgres=# \sf pg_encoding_to_char
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(integer)
 RETURNS name
 LANGUAGE internal
 STABLE STRICT
AS $function$PG_encoding_to_char$function$
```

Comment: Using `\x` first to turn on expanded display also helps with readability.

Comment: This was helpful -- thanks! -- though oddly including the parens (e.g., `\sf shared.is_authorized()`) failed with `function ... does not exist` while omitting the parens worked fine (e.g., `\sf shared.is_authorized`). (psql 12.9)

Answer (score 33):

There are many possibilities. Simplest way is to just use pgAdmin and get this from SQL window. However if you want to get this programmatically then examinate [`pg_proc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-proc.html) and [`pg_trigger`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-trigger.html) system catalogs or [`routines`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-routines.html) and [`triggers`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/infoschema-triggers.html) views from information schema (that's SQL standard way, but it might not cover all features especially PostgreSQL-specific). For example:

```sql
SELECT
    routine_definition 
FROM
    information_schema.routines 
WHERE
    specific_schema LIKE 'public'
    AND routine_name LIKE 'functionName';
```

Comment: Mmmm.. I have PGPSQL functions, that have an empty routine_defintion, and state 'EXTERNAL' in the field routine_body. Any hint where i can find those?

Comment: +1 This is more standard/portable solution. For views the SQL is: `SELECT view_definition FROM information_schema.views WHERE table_schema = ? AND table_name = ?`

Comment: But what about the case where a function name is not unique because someone made functions with the same name and different function arguments?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47341513/postgresql-how-to-display-function-or-trigger-or-view-code-for-a-unique-item

Comment: @alfonx see `pgproc.prosrc` column

Comment: I happy with this solution but is there any reason why use ``LIKE`` oprator?

Answer (score 23):

Slightly more than just displaying the function, how about getting the edit in-place facility as well.

`\ef <function_name>` is very handy. It will open the source code of the function in editable format.
You will not only be able to view it, you can edit and execute it as well.

Just `\ef` without function_name will open editable CREATE FUNCTION template.

For further reference -> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html

Comment: After editing function need to enter  \g command to update function.

Answer (score 22):

`\sf` function_name in psql yields editable source code of a single function.

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html:

> \sf[+] function_description
>   This command fetches and shows the definition of the named function, in the form of a CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION command.
>
> If + is appended to the command name, then the output lines are numbered, with the first line of the function body being line 1.

Comment: shows the source code of a function. \ef function name opens it in editable templet

Comment: This should absolutely be the accepted answer! It's just a three-character command - that's it.

Answer (score 14):

additionally to @franc's answer you can use this from sql interface:

```
select 
    prosrc
from pg_trigger, pg_proc
where
 pg_proc.oid=pg_trigger.tgfoid
 and pg_trigger.tgname like '<name>'
```

(taken from here: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.BSF.4.10.10009140858080.28013-100000@megazone23.bigpanda.com)

Answer (score 8):

Since Version: psql (9.6.17, server 11.6)

I have tried all of above answer but For me

```
postgres=> \sf jsonb_extract_path_text
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_catalog.jsonb_extract_path_text(from_json jsonb, VARIADIC path_elems text[])
 RETURNS text
 LANGUAGE internal
 IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE STRICT
AS $function$jsonb_extract_path_text$function$



postgres=> \df+
ERROR:  column p.proisagg does not exist
LINE 6:   WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
               ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "p.prolang".
```

df seems not working for me.

Comment: This seems to happen with an outdated version of psql, e. g. when `psql --version` prints a version like 10.x and the server is 11+ https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/238906

Answer (score 7):

To list all functions:

```
select n.nspname as function_schema,
       p.proname as function_name,
       l.lanname as function_language,
       case when l.lanname = 'internal' then p.prosrc
            else pg_get_functiondef(p.oid)
            end as definition,
       pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as function_arguments,
       t.typname as return_type
from pg_proc p
left join pg_namespace n on p.pronamespace = n.oid
left join pg_language l on p.prolang = l.oid
left join pg_type t on t.oid = p.prorettype 
where n.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
order by function_schema,
             function_name;
```

Now if you want to search a specific word or text in all function is something like that, make sure you replace your text in the function:

```
with tbl as (
select n.nspname as function_schema,
       p.proname as function_name,
       l.lanname as function_language,
       case when l.lanname = 'internal' then p.prosrc
            else pg_get_functiondef(p.oid)
            end as definition,
       pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as function_arguments,
       t.typname as return_type
from pg_proc p
left join pg_namespace n on p.pronamespace = n.oid
left join pg_language l on p.prolang = l.oid
left join pg_type t on t.oid = p.prorettype 
where n.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
)
    select *
    from tbl
    where definition ilike '%word or text you want to search%'
    order by function_schema,
             function_name;
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can show the code of `my_func()` function with [\sf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-SF) as shown below:

```
\sf public.my_func
```

*Memos:

- You can omit the schema `public.`.
- You can also show the code of a procedure with `\sf`.
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524859/show-full-stored-function-or-procedure-code-in-postgresql/77836599#77836599) explains how to show the code of a function in detail.

And, you can show the code of `my_t` trigger with [pg_get_triggerdef()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html),[pg_trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-trigger.html) and the OID(Object identifier) of `my_t` trigger as shown below:

```sql
SELECT pg_get_triggerdef((SELECT oid FROM pg_trigger WHERE tgname = 'my_t'));
```

*Memos:

- [My answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/331024/how-can-i-show-the-content-of-a-trigger-with-psql/1151915#1151915) explains how to show the code of a trigger.

In addition, you can show the code of `my_v` view with [\sv](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-SV) as shown below:

```
\sv public.my_v
```

*Memos:

- You can omit the schema `public.`.
- [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634322/show-the-create-view-code-for-a-view-in-postgresql/77822616#77822616) explains how to show the code of a view in detail.