# How to save query in psql by terminal

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-10

I created a query in PSQL and run and would like to save it.
Query example:

```
CREATE VIEW total_revenue_per_customer AS SELECT
customers.id, customers.first_name, customers.last_name,
SUM(items.price) FROM customers                                                          
INNER JOIN purchases ON customers.id = purchases.customer_id
INNER JOIN items ON purchases.item_id = items.id
GROUP BY customers.id;
```

What is the commando to save my query by terminal?

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14634322/how-to-see-the-create-view-code-for-a-view-in-postgresql) for retreiving the `create` statement of an existing view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start, I create an empty text file in my working directory:

```
filename.txt     ("remember to give permission to edit and modify")
```

Now, using the psql meta-command,\o we can arrange for future query results to be written to the provided filename.

```
\o filename.txt
```

Displayed above, we can see one variation of the easy syntax structure is:

```
\o filename.txt
```

creating my query and run

```
CREATE VIEW total_revenue_per_customer AS SELECT
customers.id, customers.first_name, customers.last_name,
SUM(items.price) FROM customers                                                          
INNER JOIN purchases ON customers.id = purchases.customer_id
INNER JOIN items ON purchases.item_id = items.id
GROUP BY customers.id;
```

Saved in out.txt

Since the `\o` meta-command is still active in the query buffer, you can clear it out, by issuing another `\o` meta-command, and continue on with normal activity, without writing anything else to the specified file.

Answer (score 0):

Last executed command can be also opened in external editor from `psql`. The command is `\e` which on most systems will open the command buffer in `vi`. This will create a temporary file but nothing stops you from saving another copy outside of the `/tmp` directory. Also, you can control your editor of choice with the environment variable `EDITOR`, which can be set without closing current `psql` session using `\setenv` command.

See the [docs for `psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-psql.html) if you want to find more useful commands. It reads really well and is in fact very helpful.