# How to generate source code for psql views

Tags: postgresql, view, jooq

For a view created using psql, I want to generate source code. The below config conveyed in jooq didn’t work.

```
sources = true
sourcesOnViews = true
```

Can you please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: What's your expectation here? That you're getting the Java/jOOQ representation for your SQL source code?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/14634322

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you've chosen will make sure the source code is registered in your generated code in `String` form. You probably expected it to produce the view code in jOOQ DSL form. You can start doing that manually starting from jOOQ 3.15 using the commercial distributions and the new [`SQLDialect.JAVA`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6277), or for free on the website: https://www.jooq.org/translate

A future version might offer to generate such code also as code generator output.