# Search text of all functions in PGAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

Using PostgreSQL with pgAdmin, and was wondering if there is a way to search ALL of the functions of a database for a particular text.

Is this possible?

Comment: In my case, I was specifically looking to see which functions used the `security definer` parameter, but couldn't find anything when I searched (with @Andreas's code) because those parameters aren't stored in prosrc. So, I ran `psql -E` argument to see what query it used under the hood for `\df+` and modified that query for the security column. A similar strategy could be used for other procedure attributes.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select proname, prosrc from pg_proc where prosrc like '%search text%';
```

see [How to display the function, procedure, triggers source code in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898453/how-to-display-the-function-procedure-triggers-source-code-in-postgresql)

Comment: You can also use ilike instead of like to search for case-insensitive text

Answer (score 7):

If schema info is required too (we work with many):

```
select
    nspname,
    proname,
    prosrc 
from pg_catalog.pg_proc pr
join pg_catalog.pg_namespace ns on ns.oid = pr.pronamespace
where prosrc ilike '%search text%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers posted by @Andreas and @steevee didn't work out for me, so I had to do the following way:

1. First enabled extended display by running `\x`
2. Then `\df+` to list down all stored procedures (in less mode by enabling extended display above) then press `/` key to search for a keyword.

Answer (score 1):

**Universal**

```
select  n.nspname as function_schema,
        p.proname as function_name,
        l.lanname as function_language,
        case when l.lanname = 'internal' then p.prosrc
            else pg_get_functiondef(p.oid)
            end as definition,
       pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as function_arguments,
       t.typname as return_type
from pg_proc p
left join pg_namespace n on p.pronamespace = n.oid
left join pg_language l on p.prolang = l.oid
left join pg_type t on t.oid = p.prorettype 
where n.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
order by function_schema,
         function_name;
```

**PostgreSQL 11+**

```
select schema_name,
       specific_name,
       kind,
       language,
       definition,
       arguments,return_type 
from (select n.nspname as schema_name,
       p.proname as specific_name,
       case p.prokind 
            when 'f' then 'FUNCTION'
            when 'p' then 'PROCEDURE'
            when 'a' then 'AGGREGATE'
            when 'w' then 'WINDOW'
            end as kind,
       l.lanname as language,
       case when l.lanname = 'internal' then p.prosrc
            else pg_get_functiondef(p.oid)
            end as definition,
       pg_get_function_arguments(p.oid) as arguments,
       t.typname as return_type
from pg_proc p
left join pg_namespace n on p.pronamespace = n.oid
left join pg_language l on p.prolang = l.oid
left join pg_type t on t.oid = p.prorettype 
where n.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
order by schema_name,
         specific_name) temp1
         where temp1.definition like '%FIND TEXT HERE%' --change text here
```