# How to get the code of system functions in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

How to get the definition of a system function? I mean the code of it.

Comment: You mean [these functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-info.html)?  Download the source code for PostGresql and get it from there.  Stored procedures?  Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524859

Comment: Almost all PostgreSQL system functions are implemented in C - you can find these codes in postgresql source code or in some public postgres git repository - for example lot of string functions are implemented in following file http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/varlena.c;h=5e2c2ddc532c604a05f365f0cf6761033a35be76;hb=HEAD

Comment: While it's badly worded this seems like a reasonable question. It's not trivial to go from "here's the function name" to "here's the code that implements it"; you have to look it up via `pg_proc.h` to find the underlying C function, whose location isn't always obvious so you may want to use `ctags` to find it.

Comment: Answer in comment form as this is closed: Download the PostgreSQL source code, or check it out from git. Get the `oid` of the system function with `SELECT 'funcname'::regproc::oid;`. Result like 2176. Look in `src/include/catalog/pg_proc.h` for the oid. You'll see something like `DATA(insert OID = 2176 ...`. The 4th-last entry is the C procedure name; it's *not* always the same as the SQL function  name (2nd field) due to overloads etc. Find the C procedure definition with 'git grep ^procname' or using ctags eg `vim -t procname`.

Comment: @CraigRinger: You might make an answer out of your comment after this one has been reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Get the oid of the system function with

```
SELECT 'funcname'::regproc::oid;
```

The result is a number like 2176.

Look in `src/include/catalog/pg_proc.h` for the oid. You'll see something like

```
DATA(insert OID = 2176 ....
```

The 4th-last entry is the C function name. It's not always the same as the SQL function name (2nd field) due to overloads etc.

Find the C procedure definition with `git grep ^procname` or using `ctags`/`cscope` eg `vim -t procname`.