# in Greenplum generate DDL of database objects

Tags: greenplum

is there any way, by which I can generate a DDL of GP Functions

My actual requirement is I want to create/generate DDL of each objects available in particular schema in separate SQL file

I am able to do it for tables and views via below script

```
tbl_list=`psql -At -c "select tablename from pg_tables where schemaname ='${PGSCHEMA}' and tablename not like '%_prt_%' order by 1;"` # Fetch all table Name
for fname in $tbl_list
do
   ddl=`PGPASSWORD='passwd' pg_dump -h 10.128.19.297 -U gpadmin jiodata -s -t "${PGSCHEMA}.$fname" >${script_dir}/${output_dir}/$fname.sql` # Fetch ddl for all tables
   #pg_dump -h 10.128.19.297 -U gpadmin jiodata -s -t "${PGSCHEMA}.$fname" >${script_dir}/${output_dir}/$fname.sql
   echo "Table DDL generated    :   "${PGSCHEMA}.$fname | tee -a ${log_file}
done
```

Did any one tried it for Functions

Please help if anyone know

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to display full stored procedure code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524859/how-to-display-full-stored-procedure-code)

Comment: `pg_dump` should include functions - at least it does that in Postgres

Answer (score 1):

Create a sql file named "get_functions.sql" with this code:

```
    select sub.function_name || '(' || array_to_string(array_agg(typname), ',') || ')'
    from    (
            select n.nspname as schema_name, proname as function_name, unnest(proallargtypes) as parm_type, unnest(proargmodes) as parm_direction
            from pg_proc p
            join pg_namespace n on p.pronamespace = n.oid
            where n.nspname = :schema_name
            ) as sub
    join pg_type t on sub.parm_type = t.oid
    where sub.parm_direction = 'i'
    group by sub.function_name;
```

Next, create a bash script with this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e

    schema_name="$1"

    if [ "$schema_name" == "" ]; then
            echo "ERROR: You must provide the schema name."
            echo "Example usage: ./runme.sh gp_toolkit"
            exit 1
    fi

    echo "pg_dump -Fc -s -n $schema_name > $schema_name.sql"
    pg_dump -Fc -s -n $schema_name > $schema_name.sql

    for i in $(psql -t -A -v schema_name="'$schema_name'" -f get_functions.sql); do
            filename=$(echo $i | tr \( _ | tr \) _)
            filename+=".sql"
            echo "cat $schema_name.sql | pg_restore -P '$i' > $filename"
            cat $schema_name.sql | pg_restore -P ''$i'' > $filename
    done
```

Fix the permissions on the script.

```
chmod 755 runme.sh
```

And execute the script.

```
./runme.sh gp_toolkit
```

This will create a file per function and it allows for overloaded functions too.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I have just tried, above SQL is not listing all the functions exist in any schema

Comment: Hi Jon, I have 243 Functions in database in a user schema but above query fetching only 33 rows, also `for i in $(psql -t -A -v schema_name="'$schema_name'" -f get_functions.sql); do` only generating **Timing is on**

Comment: Try "select * from pg_proc" to see if you can find the functions.  It might be in a different schema than you think.  To remove the timing is on, remove the entries from your .psqlrc file or move the SQL to the bash script and use -c instead of -f.  e.g. psql -c "select ...." instead of "psql -f file.sql".  One more thing, the catalog is case sensitive.